How to correctly get the coordinates of the cursor relative to the parent element?
Problem: There are 2 events - imgMousePressEventand imgMouseMoveEvent. When I click on the first one, I get the coordinates of the cursor's starting point. Then, when the left mouse button is pressed, the square is drawn in real time. However, the received coordinates in both cases are always 10 pixels below the cursor. What can be the problem? The code is attached:
 def imgMousePressEvent(self, event):
        if self.selectButton.isChecked() and self.Img_View_label.pixmap().isNull()!=True:
           self.drawing=True
        #    cur_pos2=self.Img_View_label.mapFromGlobal(QCursor.pos())
        #    self.x0=cur_pos2.x()
        #    self.y0=cur_pos2.y()
           self.x0=event.x()
           self.y0=event.y()

def imgMouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.drawing and self.Img_View_label.pixmap().isNull()!=True:
            # cur_pos2=self.Img_View_label.mapFromGlobal(QCursor.pos())
            # self.x1=cur_pos2.x()
            # self.y1=cur_pos2.y()
            self.x1=event.x()
            self.y1=event.y()
            if self.mousemode=="Select":
                painter=QPainter()
                tempImg=self.editImg.toImage()
                painter.begin(tempImg)
                pen=QPen(Qt.GlobalColor.red,2,Qt.PenStyle.DashDotDotLine,Qt.PenCapStyle.RoundCap)
                painter.setPen(pen)
                painter.drawRect(self.x0,self.y0,self.x1-self.x0,self.y1-self.y0)
                painter.end()
                self.Img_View_label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(tempImg))

The problem screenshot

Also, I want to ask - how to load images at the moment of editing, so that the image is inserted and not the link?

I would like to add that the commented blocks were previously used to get the coordinates. The modified version gets the same result
I tried to find information on Stackoverflow forum/guides on the internet/change the way of getting coordinates at the code level

You're most certainly overriding the mouse event handlers in the wrong class (possibly the top level window), which is always discouraged, especially for this situations. Do it in the proper widget, which is the one in which drawing should happen and for which mouse handling is relevant (self.Img_View_label). Besides, search the QWidget docs for functions having names starting with map.

@musicamante I'm overriding the event handler in the main window class, yes. Since I have the UI file separate where the QLabel object is created, I'm not quite sure how I should rewrite the call correctly now so that nothing breaks. Just transfer the written code and call MyQLabel instead of QLabel is not a right decision, as most of the objects are already lost. Isn't there some variant to get normal coordinates without overriding in UI file? Also, I noticed that changing the size of the main window affects the delta between the real position and what is drawn.

You can use custom subclasses with UI files created in designer, just search about widget promotion. If the position changes upon resizing, then it may be due to the usage of layouts and/or the QLabel having an alignment set (possibly, centered). Using the subclass will solve the main issue (since you'll have events in local coordinates), for the alignment you must translate the position based on the size of the label in relation to that of the pixmap. Be aware that most of the time image editing is better achieved through the graphics view framework.

@musicamante Good afternoon/evening once again. The problem with the cursor position was, once more, extremely simple. QLabel had the horizontal and vertical alignment parameter "Center". This caused the coordinates to be calculated incorrectly. After aligning to the left and top edges, respectively, this “bug” has disappeared
